# how do I include .js link into another .js?

Tags: javascript, include

ok let's say I have these two links

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

I'm using these as my javascript sources

and I created another file called

```
<script src="testing.js"></script>
```

but in my html I want to show the script src="testing.js" I am able to somehow put the first two links into the testing.js file?

so in my html it'll only show

```
<script src="testing.js"></script>
```

but actually it's running three scripts...

Comment: show us what you have written in your testing.js file..

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly link a `.js` file from a `.js` file

Check this: [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file)

It clearly says what can you do to link a `.js` in a `.js` file

Answer (score 1):

Solution from about.com:

In your `testing.js` file create this function:

```
function addJavascript(jsname,pos) {
var th = document.getElementsByTagName(pos)[0];
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
s.setAttribute('src',jsname);
th.appendChild(s);
}
```

Later call the function using:

```
addJavascript('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js','head');
addJavascript('http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js','head');
```

There are few other ways, but not all of them are compatible with all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can only include a script file in an HTML page, not in another script file

Answer (score 0):

You can use requireJS for Asynchronous loading of JS files. If that is an option, [A tutorial to get you started](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) can be found here.

P.S. I know that this is not what OP asked but the requirement is very similar to this.